# how to count reps for each repeated values based on ID?

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column "period" based on counting of date by ID.

I used the "freq" function, but it isn't working.

Input

```
ID  Date
A   20/05/2023
A   20/05/2023
B   21/05/2023
B   22/05/2023
B   23/05/2023
C   22/05/2023
C   23/05/2023
D   22/05/2023
D   22/05/2023
D   23/05/2023
D   24/05/2023
```

Output

```
ID     Date       period
A   20/05/2023    1
A   20/05/2023    1 
B   21/05/2023    1 
B   22/05/2023    2
B   23/05/2023    3
C   22/05/2023    1
C   23/05/2023    2 
D   22/05/2023    1
D   22/05/2023    1
D   23/05/2023    2 
D   24/05/2023    3
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyverse)

output_df <- input_df |>
  mutate(
    period = cumsum(Date != lag(Date, default = "0/0/0000")),
    .by = ID
  )
```

Note that the `.by` option in `dplyr::mutate` (part of `tidyverse`) is reasonably new, so if you  have an older version you might get an error.  The older way to do this was

```
library(tidyverse)

output_df <- input_df |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(
    period = cumsum(Date != lag(Date, default = "0/0/0000"))
  ) |>
  ungroup()
```

Comment: If the OP is using dplyr >= 1.1.0 they could also do `consecutive_id(ID, Date)` instead of `cumsum`.

Comment: Good point, @LMc!  I'm so used to (over) using `cumsum` for these types of tasks that I hadn't looked up the newer/fancier ways to accomplish it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `ave`

```r
df$Period <- ave(df$Date, df$ID, FUN = function(x) {
  as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y") - min(as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y")) + 1
})
```

Resulting in

```r
df
#>    ID       Date Period
#> 1   A 20/05/2023      1
#> 2   A 20/05/2023      1
#> 3   B 21/05/2023      1
#> 4   B 22/05/2023      2
#> 5   B 23/05/2023      3
#> 6   C 22/05/2023      1
#> 7   C 23/05/2023      2
#> 8   D 22/05/2023      1
#> 9   D 22/05/2023      1
#> 10  D 23/05/2023      2
#> 11  D 24/05/2023      3
```

Note that the main difficulty here is that you are storing dates as strings, so you have to convert them every time you want to calculate something. Best to store them as actual date objects and only convert to your chosen format when you want to produce a finished output from your script.

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 
"D", "D", "D"), Date = c("20/05/2023", "20/05/2023", "21/05/2023", 
"22/05/2023", "23/05/2023", "22/05/2023", "23/05/2023", "22/05/2023", 
"22/05/2023", "23/05/2023", "24/05/2023")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try this

```
transform(
    df,
    period = as.integer(ave(Date, ID, FUN = \(x) match(x, unique(x))))
)
```

or

```
transform(df,period = as.integer(ave(Date, ID, FUN = factor)))
```

which gives

```
   ID       Date period
1   A 20/05/2023      1
2   A 20/05/2023      1
3   B 21/05/2023      1
4   B 22/05/2023      2
5   B 23/05/2023      3
6   C 22/05/2023      1
7   C 23/05/2023      2
8   D 22/05/2023      1
9   D 22/05/2023      1
10  D 23/05/2023      2
11  D 24/05/2023      3
```